# How to remove unmatched part from string using JS/jQUery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have regex `/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\\=]*)/g` for checking valid URL. But it accepts:

```
https://www.google.com
google.com
https://google.com
dev.google.com
```

Thats fine with me but I want that when user inputs these values filtered value will be `google.com` which I have to pass through `AJAX` but the inputs will be same on `UI` part ( means browser ). I know this is possible but I can't.

Any reference will be helpfull
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want domain name and that too changed to have ".com" even for ".co"?

Comment: @binariedMe sorry my mistake. I have updated. :) I want only domain part `google.com`

Comment: I have added a regex for you to test your req

Comment: yes also know the `regex`. I want the `exec` part which @sinha has given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
var regExp = /\w+\.\w+(?=$|\/)/;
var matches1 = regExp.exec("https://www.google.com/images");
var matches2 = regExp.exec("google.com");
var matches3 = regExp.exec("https://google.com");
var matches4 = regExp.exec("dev.google.com");


//matches1[0] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(matches1[0]);
console.log(matches2[0]);
console.log(matches3[0]);
console.log(matches4[0]);
```

All of the above will give you 'google.com'

Comment: Thanx for your answer. It's working and saves my time.

Comment: You copied exact solution from previous answer. 

Comment: @revo, as I understood the question was about to getting the filtered text out of the input so I tried my best to share a complete solution that might be helpful. There is nothing to 'copy', regex are not secrets right ;)

Comment: You didn't provide a different solution so it's called a *copy*. Further more adding code sample implementation doesn't mean answering the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regular exp. :

```
var a = /(\w*\.\w*)$|(\w*\.\w*)(\/)/;
```

Explanation :

first part of OR checks for last occurance of x.y
second part of OR checks for x.y right before starting of "/" keyword

Answer (score 0):

Check either matching section should appear at the end of URL or before any path, fragment or query string:

```
\w+\.\w+(?=$|[\/?#])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ4uTY/1)